# Как сделать push menu с изменением ширины контента?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Всем привет. 
Нужно сделать меню, которое будет выезжать слева, но при этом контент справа не должен залезать под экран справа(простите за повторение), а пропорционально менял свою ширину. Решений с push menu множество, но я не смог найти достойное для пропорционального изменения ширины контента. Я не прошу сделать за меня. Посоветуйте, если знаете, готовые решения или как сделать самому. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector('.push-menu').classList.toggle('visible')
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.push-menu {
  width: 0;
  background: #ccc;
  transition: all .3s;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.push-menu.visible {
  width: 100px;
}

.content {
  background: #000;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all .3s;
}
```

```html
<button>push me</button>

<div class=container>
  <div class=push-menu></div>
  <div class=content>حدى تم لكون قررت ديسمبر. ما تلك الجنوب جزيرتي. بعد بلاده إحكام مساعدة أم. والقرى الأوروبي أخذ في. الجوي المتساقطة، و فقد, أعلنت الإمداد التكاليف إذ كلّ, ما كثيرة السبب بمحاولة جعل. أحكم حالية شيء عن.

إذ أهّل الإنزال دون. مايو وجزر ذلك من, الأمريكية تشيكوسلوفاكيا كلا أن, وبدأت انذار ٣٠ قام. عن جهة اعلان إنطلاق, جيوب يعادل الإتفاقية فقد أن. بحق تنفّس كُلفة الجنوب في, أي كلّ جيما بالمطالبة. أضف جدول الأوروبية، ان, بـ إيو وأزيز الصفحة الشهيرة. تلك في لإعادة اللازمة واقتصار, أمّا للحكومة التجارية هذا ٣٠, الشهير تكتيكاً الدولارات دار أي.

عن استبدال والعتاد الأثناء، كما. جُل وبدأت الجديدة، الأمريكي لم. ارتكبها لبلجيكا، الاندونيسية مع هذه. به، كل التحالف بريطانيا وبالتحديد،, جدول الأولية والنفيس يتم كل, و جنوب إختار السيطرة على. بين قد تُصب بالعمل مواقعها, لكون انذار العدّ أم إيو, تم وانهاء لهيمنة معزّزة هذا. دون خيار الدول الإقتصادية عل, ضرب ما وبحلول ويتّفق بمباركة.</div>
</div>
```